# Understanding how rolling hash works with modulus in Rabin Karp algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, hash, rabin-karp

I am having trouble understanding how the rolling hash algorithm works after the hash has been reduced to modulus value by dividing by a prime number.

Consider the sequence of 5 digits in the number `123456`.

The first chunk is `12345`. I store the value, in the next window, 6 comes in and 1 goes out.

So the new hash will be `(12345-1*10^4)*10 + 6 = 23456`. This is fairly intuitive.

As obvious, these numbers are large, so we need a modulus function to keep them small. Suppose I take `101` as the prime number for this purpose.

So `12345` will reduce to `23`. How then, from this, will I derive the rolling hash for the next window, `23456`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You calculate it the same way you calculate `23456`, but always with modulo `101`.

```
(((23 - (10^4 mod 101))*10) mod 101 + 6) mod 101 = 24.
```

which is the value you want because `23456 mod 101 = 24`.

Comment: Thanks. That was easy to understand!

Comment: Did you miss the first one? Shouldn't it be (((23 - (1*10^4 mod 101))*10) mod 101 + 6) mod 101 = 24 ?

Answer (score 2):

Answer by @dejvuth is right - i would add this specifically when doing rabin-karp is that sometimes you may end up with a -ve modulus value - in that case it is better to take the +ve equivalent of that modulus value - so that checking if the same modulus was seen before is easier.

For example:
with this pattern `"abcdabc"` -
and hash function:
`hash(i) = (49*S[i]+7*S[i+1]+1*S[i+2])%1123`

Results in:

```
"abc" -> 1046
"bcd" -> 1103
"cda" -> 33
"dab" -> 62
"abc" -> -77
```

second occurence of `"abc"` results is `-77` that is modulo equivalent of `1046` since `(-77 + 1123 = 1046)`

PS: i don't have enough "reputation" at this time to add this as a comment..

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this answer. I do not know modular arithmetic yet, so I wasted 2 hours on basically rectifying what was not broken.